# Set static Text to Vector in Openlayers 6

Tags: openlayers

I am trying to set "Epicenter" to Vector created I am using `Text` , `Fill` and `Stroke` for `Style` then send this `style` to my vector but it shows nothing.

```
    const epicenterStyle = new ol.style.Style({
        text: new ol.style.Text({
            font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color:'#000'
            }),
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color:'#fff',
                width:3
            }),
            textAlign:'left',
            offsetX:2
        })
    });
    pointEarthquake = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            features: [position]
        }),
        visible: true,
        title: "Evento sísmico",
        style: epicenterStyle.setText('Epicenter')
    })
```

Also tried on Vector `style: epicenterStyle.getText().setText('Epicenter')`

If i `console.log(epicenterStyle)` i get this:
[image: result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setText()` updates the style, but it does not return the style

Call `setText()` first then use the updated style

```
epicenterStyle.getText().setText('Epicenter');
pointEarthquake = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        features: [position]
    }),
    visible: true,
    title: "Evento sísmico",
    style: epicenterStyle
})
```

```html
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.9.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      html, body, .map {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.9.0/build/ol.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      const map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          })
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: [0, 0],
          zoom: 4
        })
      });
      const position = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point([0, 0]));
      const epicenterStyle = new ol.style.Style({
        text: new ol.style.Text({
            font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color:'#000'
            }),
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color:'#fff',
                width:3
            }),
            textAlign:'left',
            offsetX:2
        })
      });
      epicenterStyle.getText().setText('Epicenter');
      const pointEarthquake = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            features: [position]
        }),
        visible: true,
        title: "Evento sísmico",
        style: epicenterStyle
      });
      map.addLayer(pointEarthquake);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tried as your example but didn't get any change, also tried using a variable like this `let updatedStyle = epicenterStyle.getText().setText('Epicenter');` then use it as `style` on Vector but get nothing again

Comment: I've adding a working code snippet

Comment: Thanks, i forgot i was using another `style`, just added in my first style and it worked